# Can't move data from access form to report

Tags: mysql, database, ms-access

I have access from with 3 input fields and "ok" button. when I press this button current form closes with save set to yes. and report opens. In report I also have 3 fields where I want to be displayed inputs from form. In reports text field I have such code:"=[Forms]![enter values]![id]". So the problem is if I don't close the from and refresh report it displays correct record. But as I want to close the form after closing on report all 3 fields are:"#Name?"

Comment: Other points: _closes form with save set to yes_ refers to the form's design, not data. Besides that - is this a bounded form? wouldn't you want to refer to the underlying table?

Comment: no it's not a bounded form

Comment: it's like writing writing some info to report and getting ready to print it. I just want to info would be written in form which pops up as a new window

Comment: There may be other methods, but if you use Access, you should know this one: a Form and Report have [RecordSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821093.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) Property, a name of a table, Query, a SELECT statment. Controls have a [ControlSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224120%28v=office.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property. Use the properties to read and write directly from Access tables. Google is full of tutorials of wizards, that point down to these two properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Forms collection contains all of the **currently open forms** in a Microsoft Access database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa210667(v=office.11).aspx). After closing a form, it can not be referred to through *Forms* collection.

Comment: Yeah I think u are right. so what u think is the solution for this problem ?

Comment: Make it simple: Create a table, MyTable, with 3 fields: Field1 Field2 and Field3. Then you open your form in design view, and from propertie window, in the Data section, select MyTable as the RecordSource, then focus on the controls (TextBoxes) and in the same place in properties window select the field you want as ControlSource. Do the same for the Report.